# How to set telerik dropdownList text?

Tags: c#, telerik

How can I set the text (or the value) of a binded telerik DropDownList ? I tried :

```
DataRow rw = GetMyData().DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];
MyDropDownList.SelectedText = rw["FieldName"].ToString();
```

and

```
MyDropDownList.DataTextField = rw["FieldName"].ToString();
```

But it doesn't seem to work..

However I can set textboxes values easily with

```
MyTxtBox.Text = rw["FieldName"].ToString();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyDropDownList.DataTextField = rw["Text"].ToString();
MyDropDownList.DataValueField = rw["ID/Value"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
MyDropDownList.DataTextField = rw["Text"].ToString();
```

Comment: The cast from Object to String is not implicit, we necessarily need ToString(). It doesn't work in both cases for me...